# Auto Complete (PHP) Buscando em Arquivo Txt

Tags: php

Arquivo txt

```
111111 Nome Sobrenome
222222 Nome Sobrenome
333333 Nome Sobrenome
```

Campo para preencher

```
<span>Aluno</span> : <input id="entry" type="text" name="test">
```

Como eu consigo fazer para que quando o usuário digitar o nome ou matrícula auto completar (buscando no arquivo.txt) e guardar em $matricula apenas com o número de matrícula?

O número de matrícula pode variar a quantidade de caracteres, mas sempre aparece no inicio.

É possível? Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que estudar as funções do PHP cara, por exemplo, ao invés de perguntar aqui, você pode ir no Google e digitar: "how to split a string" que é "como dividir/cortar uma string", vai vir a função `explode()` por exemplo, daí você implementa. Outra coisa: "how to get content from a txt file" que é "como pegar conteúdo de uma arquivo txt" daí na documentação do PHP vai aparecer `file_get_contents()`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("file.txt");

$rows = explode("\n", $contents);
$cols = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $cols[] = explode(" ", $row);
}
```

Agora você tem um array +/- como esse:

```
[
  ["1", "Marcelo", "Rafael"],
  ["2", "Ana",     "Clara"],
  ["3", "Berta",   "Jota"]
]
```

Agora, como voce quer fazer autocomplete, voce deverá usar Ajax, daí só estudar caso não saiba. Sites para aprender:

w3 é mais prático e rápido
[W3Schools Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

ou MDN que é mais "atualizado"
[MDN Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

Não respondi diretamente sua pergunta, mas estou aqui para ajudar, flw.